# How to block outgoing connection to external website with ufw?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I'm using debian10 ufw, command as next:

```
ufw deny out to 10.192.225.199 port 80
```

And the status as next:

```
# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

10.192.225.199 80          DENY OUT    Anywhere
```

But after that, I still could visit external web successfully:

```
 curl http://10.192.225.199
```

What happened? Further more, how to block all outgoing traffic to all external website (Just 80 port of other site), not just 10.192.225.199?

Comment: Straight `iptables` solution: `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP`.

Comment: @iBug Anyways using ufw could realize the same function?

Comment: Your UFW command is working for me. I don't know what's wrong